# Questions about the Bochner integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

I'v seen a proposition saying that:

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ be a Bochner integrable function and $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure. Let $\left(A_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets and $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$, then
$$
\int_{A} f \mathrm{~d} \mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{A_{n}} f \mathrm{~d} \mu
$$
and the sum is absolutely convergent.

**I think the condition '$\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite is unnecessary', what's wrong with my proof?**

My proof:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\|\int_{A_{n}} f \mathrm{~d} \mu\right\| \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{A_{n}}\|f(\omega)\| \mathrm{d} \mu=\int_{A}\|f(\omega)\| \mathrm{d} \mu<\infty
$$
thus the sum absolutely converges.
Then we just need to verify
$$
\left\|\int_{A} f \mathrm{~d} \mu - \sum_{n=1}^{m} \int_{A_{n}} f \mathrm{~d} \mu \right\|\rightarrow 0 (m\rightarrow 0)
$$
Obviously,
$$
\left\|\int_{A} f \mathrm{~d} \mu - \sum_{n=1}^{m} \int_{A_{n}} f \mathrm{~d} \mu \right\| = \left\|      \int_{\bigcup_{n=m+1}^{\infty}  A_{n}   }                   f \mathrm{~d} \mu\right\| \leq   \int_{\bigcup_{n=m+1}^{\infty} A_{n}   }                  \| f \mathrm\|{~d}\mu = \sum_{n=m+ 1}^{\infty} \int_{A_{n}}\|f\| \mathrm{d} \mu \rightarrow 0
$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: you are totally right: there is no need of $\sigma $-finiteness for the monotone convergence theorem